Add script to IP port on Microsoft Server 2019 as Print Server
Im currently trying to setup fake printer on server to obtain files and store them on disc to use them in another app. I need to intercept print request from other computer when it choose this fake printer and use windows build in print action (ctrl + p).
Now printer is added, and is visible through network -> server computer -> printer. I can use it as printing device for example in word document. On a server i can run powershell script for only monitoring port and already created print jobs.
I have seen a possibility to add script in this window, but there should be also option for it and im thinking that should be albe to intercept request at its start.
configue tcp/ip port window
Have anybody else wanted to intercept printer jobs to acces files? Does windows server need additional roles or options to be able to do that? Or maybe i should add specific driver for fake printer. I have seen hp universal print monitor port but i didnt use it. I have created tcp/ip port.
Also i heard about custom print processor but its is also black magic for me haha.
I used console app in c# to also monitor jobs but cannot extract actual file from it. I dont think it is usefull but it showed me each print job request to printers or fake printers throught server
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winspool.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winspool.lib")

#define MAX_PRINTER_NAME 256
#define MAX_JOB_NAME 256

void SavePrintJobData(HANDLE hPrinter, JOB_INFO_2* pJobInfo) {
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0, dwReturned = 0;
    BYTE* pJobData = NULL;

    if (!GetJob(hPrinter, pJobInfo->JobId, 2, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded)) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            pJobData = (BYTE*)malloc(dwNeeded);
            if (pJobData) {
                if (GetJob(hPrinter, pJobInfo->JobId, 2, pJobData, dwNeeded, &dwReturned)) {
                    JOB_INFO_2* pFullJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_2*)pJobData;

                    char filename[MAX_PATH];
                    sprintf_s(filename, sizeof(filename), "C:\\PrintJobs\\%s", pFullJobInfo->pDocument);

                    FILE* file;
                    if (fopen_s(&file, filename, "wb") == 0) {
                        if (pFullJobInfo->pDatatype && strcmp(pFullJobInfo->pDatatype, "RAW") == 0) {
                            // Próba pobrania surowych danych zadania
                            DWORD cbWritten;
                            if (ReadPrinter(hPrinter, file, pFullJobInfo->Size, &cbWritten)) {
                                printf("Raw data saved to: %s\n", filename);
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("Error reading raw data.\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("Jos isn in raw format.\n");
                        }
                        fclose(file);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Error open file to save.\n");
                    }
                }
                free(pJobData);
            }
        }
    }
}

void MonitorPrintJobs() {
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO* pInfo = NULL;
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS options;
    HANDLE hChange = NULL;
    DWORD dwChange;

    PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE types[1];
    types[0].Type = JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE;
    types[0].Reserved0 = 0;
    types[0].Reserved1 = 0;
    types[0].Reserved2 = 0;
    types[0].Count = 1;
    types[0].pFields = (PWORD)calloc(1, sizeof(WORD));
    types[0].pFields[0] = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT;

    options.Version = 2;
    options.Flags = 0;
    options.Count = 1;
    options.pTypes = types;

    HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS defaults = { NULL, NULL, PRINTER_ACCESS_USE };

     if (OpenPrinter(NULL, &hPrinter, &defaults)) {
        hChange = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinter, PRINTER_CHANGE_ALL, 0, &options);

        if (hChange != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            while (TRUE) {
                dwChange = WaitForSingleObject(hChange, INFINITE);
                if (dwChange == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                    DWORD dwResult;
                    if (FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, &dwResult, &options, (LPVOID*)&pInfo)) {
                        for (DWORD i = 0; i < pInfo->Count; i++) {
                            if (pInfo->aData[i].Type == JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE && pInfo->aData[i].Field == JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT) {
                                JOB_INFO_2* pJobInfo = NULL;
                                DWORD cbNeeded = 0, cReturned = 0;

                                EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 2, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &cReturned);
                                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
                                    pJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_2*)malloc(cbNeeded);
                                    if (EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 2, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded, &cReturned)) {
                                        SavePrintJobData(hPrinter, pJobInfo);
                                    }
                                    free(pJobInfo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                }
            }
            FindClosePrinterChangeNotification(hChange);
        }
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    }

    free(types[0].pFields);
}

int main() {
    MonitorPrintJobs();
    return 0;
}

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Sounds like you should really be using some proper print server software. But you can set a file as the Port in Print Management on the server, then it will always just output to that file. Monitor the file using FileSystemWatcher or similar and copy it to elsewhere. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169728/14868997

The link you provided is for a simple generic print driver with no bells and whistles.  It does not have an option for running scripts.

@jdweng but using the fileSystemWatcher the file can be watched and as soon as it's created a piece of code can run.

Okey. I will try to use print to pdf with ghostcsript and radmon. I see that there is alse automatically output dir set so it also will be nice to use. Lets see what i can achieve
